# Configuring Automatic Start of Azure Virtual Machine upon Remote Desktop Login

Tags: azure, automation, virtual-machine, startup

We have created an Azure virtual machine 'Standard NV12ads A10 v5' with Windows 10 as the operating system. In order to reduce costs, we would like to find a way to have the machine powered on only when strictly necessary (ideally, when someone is connected via RDP). Currently, we automatically shut down the machine at a specific time, but we are looking for a solution that automatically powers on the machine as soon as someone connects via RDP. Additionally, the solution should be user-friendly as our users are not technical experts. What options are available to achieve this and minimize the impact on the users?

Answer (score 0):

> Configuring Automatic Start of Azure Virtual Machine upon Remote Desktop Login.

I have created a `Service Principal` and given a role to the **Virtual Machine** for accessing an **Azure VM**

Here is the **PowerShell** script that will power on the **VM** when someone connects via **RDP**

```
  $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<your-service-principal-password>" -AsPlainText -Force  
    $credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList "<your-service-principal-application-id>", $securePassword  
    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId "<your-tenant-id>"  
    $vmName = "vmname"  
    $rdpPort = 3389  
    $ResourceGroup = "qrgname"
    $isPoweredOn = (Get-AzVM -VMName $vmName).PowerState -eq "stopped"  
    if ($isPoweredOn -ne $true) {  
    Start-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $vmName  
    Start-Sleep -s 60  
    Write-Output "Started VM."  
    }  
    Write-Output "Launching RDP"
    mstsc /v:VMPublicIP:3389 /prompt
```

**Result:**

[image]

Once ran the above script, **VM** will start automatically with **RDP** session as below